# CefSharp not raising Html5 Drag n Drop API events

Tags: drag-and-drop, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp in a WPF application. I need to handle the HTML5 Drag n'Drop API events, but I guess they are not being thrown by CefSharp. I'm loading this [HTML page](http://html5demos.com/drag) and it is not working as expected. I've already tried tweaking the browser settings (DragDropDisabled) with no success. I'm using CefSharp version 1.25.7 and also tried upgrading to the most recent version with no success either.

It seems that only the "dragstart" event is being thrown.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

1.25 is old and unsupported. Test with all active branches. Also test other examples, e.g. MDN drag&drop examples. WPF d&d was implemented in this PR: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1210